# Drawing a polygon when the mouse is clicked

Tags: c, opengl, glut

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>

double width=600;
double height=600;

void processMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    glColor4f(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

static void render()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glutMouseFunc(processMouse);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);                                         
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);   
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow("Board");  
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

The render function is executed, and every time a click is performed, it should start the function processMouse.
So if the mouse is clicked, all the window should become red with the instructions:

```
    glColor4f(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
```

But when I click the mouse I notice a strange behaviour: only a part of the window gets colored, the part at bottom left (instead of all the screen).
The window remains in this state, until I open a google chrome window.If I open a google chrome (or another graphical application), all the window become colored of red.
Why this? I also have problems with more complex programs, it seems like sometime the glVertex instructions are ignored.If I try debugging the program with fprintf it appears that everything is ok, and everything seems to go like expected (for example I tried to print mouse coordinates in the processMouse function, they were ok), except for the fact that what I draw is ignored.

Edit:
I have modified this code but it still has the same problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>

double width=600;
double height=600;
bool down=false;;

// http://elleestcrimi.me/2010/10/06/mouseevents-opengl/


static void render()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    if(down)
    {
        glColor4f(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
    }
}

void processMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(state==GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        down=true;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc,argv);                                         
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);   
glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
glutCreateWindow("Board"); 
glutMouseFunc(processMouse);
glutDisplayFunc(render);
glutMainLoop();
}
```

Still getting only a part of the screen red.

PS: Solved using glutSwapBuffers(), thanks.

Comment: I can't find `down=false` anywhere in your code. This means the immediate drawing is done exactly _once_.

Comment: In the first declaration: bool down = false, yes the goal is to do it  only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using double buffering with GLUT, you need to call `glutSwapBuffers()` to see the result of the draw.

Add this to the end of your `render()` function and it will work fine.

Comment: I have modified the code (see the edit), but I still have the same problem.